# Eclipse Wildfly 12 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in WAR

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, wildfly

My war-file is generated by maven.
In this war-file there is `WEB-INF\lib\spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar` containing the class `org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletHttpHandlerAdapter$HandlerResultSubscriber`
But why i'm getting this exeption...?

> 13:07:57,345 WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (Weld Thread Pool -- 3) Failed to define class org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServletHttpHandlerAdapter$HandlerResultSubscriber in Module "deployment.univers-web-2.0.3.RELEASE.war" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/http/server/reactive/ServletHttpHandlerAdapter$HandlerResultSubscriber (Module "deployment.univers-web-2.0.3.RELEASE.war" from Service Module Loader): org/reactivestreams/Subscriber

Here my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>univers-web</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath></relativePath>
</parent>

<properties>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>10.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.bwulf</groupId>
        <artifactId>univers-ui</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Are you sure that there is no multiple versions of your app in deployment? This exception can occur if there is more than one copy of that class, and classloader cannot determine which one to load.

Comment: @TatuLund I deleted the the "temp and deployment"-file in widfly. After that i checked used enviroment and fix all to the same. Now it worked. Thanks for hint.